# Primary key value in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity layout contains int value of venue (`VenueId` prop), its own `id` and other information.

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Venue_Layout] FOREIGN KEY ([VenueId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Venue] ([Id])
```

When I trying to add two layouts with the same `VenueId`, I'm getting this error

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'DataAccess.Models.LayoutModel' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration."

My entity code:

```
[Table("Layout")]
public class LayoutModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int VenueId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Insertion code:

```
var layouts = new List<LayoutModel>
            {
                new LayoutModel { VenueId = 1, Description = "First layout" },
                new LayoutModel { VenueId = 1, Description = "Second layout" },
            };
            _context.Layouts.AddRange(layouts);
            _context.SaveChanges();
```

I'm not allowed to use navigation properties

Comment: You're probably trying to add 2 `LayoutModel` with the same `Id`

Comment: Can you try decorating the properties with [Column(Order = 0)] for Id and [Column(Order = 1)] for VenueId. Also, decorate VenueId using [ForeignKey("Venue")]. Also, could you paste INSERT values for Id, venueId combo?

Comment: @Magnetron they have differt id's

Comment: @sam ```var layouts = new List<LayoutModel>
            {
                new LayoutModel { Id = 1, VenueId = 1, Description = "First layout" },
                new LayoutModel { Id = 2, VenueId = 1, Description = "Second layout" },
            };
            _context.Layouts.AddRange(layouts);
            _context.SaveChanges();``` I have one Venue with Id one. I can't decorate decorate VenueId using [ForeignKey("Venue")] because i can't add navigation properies

Comment: @Nicefsf:  Please update the post instead of comments. When Id is identity column, why are you explicitly setting Id to 1 and/or 2? Please remove that assignment statement.

Answer (score 1):

Id column or property is marked as identity column in the definition of LayoutViewModel

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

So, no need to assign it explicitly as it will be populated by Database automatically after the row is inserted into Layout table. Please update your layouts population as below to remove Id assignment:

```
var layouts = new List<LayoutModel> { 
    new LayoutModel { /*Id = 1,*/ VenueId = 1, Description = "First layout" }, 
    new LayoutModel { /*Id = 2, */ VenueId = 1, Description = "Second layout" }
};
// code smell
foreach(var layout in layouts)
{
     context.Entry(layout).State = EntityState.Added;
}
_context.Layouts.AddRange(layouts);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Also, please update your LayoutModel as below:

```
public class LayoutModel
{
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     [Key]
     [Column(Order = 0)]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Key]
     [Column(Order = 1)]
     //[ForeignKey("Venue")]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
     public int VenueId { get; set; }

     //public virtual VenueModel Venue { get; set; } //Please correct Venue property type
}
```

Also, please verify whether Venue is loaded into _context.Layouts or not.

Comment: I've added id's assignment just before pasting this code here

Comment: @Nicefsf, could you please update your post to depict the code that is actually throwing the exception. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Nicefsf Could you please decorate VenueId with ForeignKey attribute?

Comment: To use [ForeignKey] i need to have Venue navigation property, but i'm not allowed to (task requirement) as i mentioned earlier

Comment: @Nicefsf Could you try manually updating EntityState as shown in my post.

Comment: It still throw the same exeption. I think that EF decided that VenueId is also PK for my table, i've tried inserting layouts with different VenueId's and that was ok

Comment: @Nicefsf  The only way to tell EF that both Id and VenueId are compostie primary keys is via Key and Column attribute combination. I hope you have used both of them in your code. Alternatively, you can remove both of them and use index on both of them in which case only Id will be marked primary key not VenueId.

Comment: @Nicefsf You can enable EF logging via _context.Database.Log = <console_or_file_target>. Please enable that and see what insert statements are being passed to database. Alternatively, please enable Sql Server profiler and verify INSERT staements there. Try to grab those insert statements and execute them manually from SSMS.

Comment: the thing is that those rows added using both SSMS and EF, but EF still throwing exception that it cann't update the object context. Nevertheless, those rows are appended successfully